# Play alert sound without alert box?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, alert

I just want to play the alert sound not really have an alert box appear. So I'm guessing I don't require any sound files or anything else. Just need to initiate an alert box and have it hidden or something....

Is this possible with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Alert box playing sound, depends on browser and operating system settings. So, you cannot rely on that.

But, you can use javascript to play sounds like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(soundfile) {
     document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
         "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"
          loop=\"false\" />";
 }
</script>
```

**Note:** And your html should have an element with id `dummy`.

Now, you can invoke `playSound` whenever you want to play some sound.

Source: http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm

As @bigblind suggested, you can use [`HTML 5 based sound`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) playing options as well.

Comment: no need ro embeds, we have HTML5 audio now in al modern browsers, and there are flash fallbacks.

Comment: There's an awesome tutorial on using it at HTML5rocks http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/. I was writing an answer based on that, but I think reading the actual tutorial would be much more useful than reading a shortened version, because it contains many important details.